# How does a CANopen frame look like, 2. What is the meaning of Transmit PDO and Receive PDO? , 3. How is a PDO mapping done programatically?

Tags: can-bus, canopen

I am unable to understand the CANopen Protocol. I am aware of the working of CAN and how a CAN frame looks like. A CAN data or remote frame contains the Start of Frame , Message Identifier Field, DLC, RTR , Data(Payload), CRC , ACk fields, etc. I am aware that the CANopen standard utilizes the CAN bus to send the CAN messages. However , the way in which a CANopen's CAN frame looks is different where it contains a COB ID+Node ID in the Message identifier field and in the payload field , it contains object dictionary related information. I would like to ask the following questions therefore:

1. How are the object dictionaries defined. I am aware that it is a
   table containing an ID , sub ID, Datatype information about the data
   it contains , the manufacturer information for the respective data
   entry , etc . Are they all hard coded as an m*n multidimensional
   array in the software stack?
2. I am confused with the terms transmit PDO and Receive PDO. Is it    similar to CAN data frame and CAN remote frame ?
3. What is PDO mapping and how can i identify which object ID in the    object dictionary is mapped to which object ID in the PDO mapping
   table. Both use the same terms Object ID ?

I am actually very new to CANopen and i have asked these questions based on my initial understanding. I was unable to find a detailed explanation in the CiA website.

Thank you in advance

Krishna

Comment: You are basically asking how the whole CANopen standard works. This is too broad a question that would take too long to explain here. You can study the basics over at [CAN in Automation](https://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/tag/CANopen/361_429_521_621_635_636_637_683_688_703_717_873_942_1034_1035_1037/183d606a966ef0a2e1432189a8ff8ce0/), the non-profit organization that "owns" the CANopen standard.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I will go through the link and get back..

Answer (score 0):

It is not so easy to understand it!!

CanOpen is a communication between Master (client) and Slave (server).
An device like a sensor is a Slave.
The slave has an OD (object directory). The manufacturer provides all informations about it.  Ex. if i want to read the temperature, its location is at adress 0x2040 at sub index 00.  Then the master (our system) needs to make this request.  To do this, you need to configure the device by sending some request  (with SDO) in order to change the TPDO1 mapping (0x1A00) and TPDO1 communication parameters (0x1800). And be able to receive by the device the temperature.  The device will not work alone.

SDO (read/write) allows OD access entries. Ex. change the TPDO1 mappings.
PDO is the output/input to the device once operational.

There is  NMT Master commands to put the device in operational mode or to send a SYNC or Heartbeat. Depends what the device needs?
Ex. 080h 00 : SYNC send by master
280h 06 E5 EF 02 00 00 00 : response of device by TPDO2
000h 02 01 1F : put the device with ID = 1F in operational mode

If you want a good example device POSITAL FRABA absolute rotary encoder with can open interface.

Hope this will help you a little bit!!!

Comment: Thank you so much Martin Pelletier. Your explanation was helpful.  This really encourages beginners like me to read further. I have obtained some basic understanding of CANopen through the CIA website and some Youtube videos.